# CSS cross browser issue with floated div

Tags: html, css

I've created a few pages in Firefox and everything was looking as it should. Made a quick flip to Chrome and Safari and noticed that my opt-in form in the header of this page is not displaying as it should. I would like for the entire opt-in div to be inside the header div. From what I can tell it is in the header div in Firefox, but pretty much every other browser shows it below the main navigation.

Here is the CSS for the header and the opt-in form that should be in it:

```
.header{height: 302px;min-width: 100%; background-color: #265f8b;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.opt-in {height: 280px; width: 800px;background-color: #c7e877;float: right;
    margin-right: 200px;margin-top: 10px;border:5px solid #8db530;
    border-radius: 10px;position: relative;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class='header'>
<img style='border: 1px solid black;' src='images/main-logo.jpg'></img>
<div class='opt-in'>


    <p>Enter your name and email below to get 
        <span style='font-weight: bolder;'>Free Instant Access</span> to the most comprehensive 
        guide available on how to ..</p>

        <p><span style='font-weight: bolder;'>Over 10,000 people</span> have enjoyed my eBook and receive  
            a weekly newsletter with exclusive tips!</p>

        <table>
            <form method='post' action='opt-in-form.php'>
            <tr><td><input type='text' name='name' value='Enter Name...' /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type='text' name='email' value='Enter Your Email...' /></td></tr>
        <input class='opt-in-button' type='image' src='images/opt-in-button.png' alt='Submit Form' />
        </table>    

        </form>


    <img class='book-cover' src="images/book-cover-new.png"></img>

</div>

</div>
```

You'll notice that I have included it in the header div and have a float right on it.

http://fairchildwebsolutions.com/packattack/index.php

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top left logo needs a `float: left`. that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Float the logo img left.

```
float:left
```

Also specify a width for the img element too. `width:auto` will do also.

Comment: that is exactly what i said

Comment: Yeah your answer appeared once i posted. Great minds and all that.

Comment: @BeniaminSzabo it's an incredibly easy question with a simple answer. It's not like he stole anything from you, it's an obvious and elementary CSS fix.

Comment: i was not saying that he stole my answer. that was not an accusation. I am sorry if it sounded like that :D

Comment: I was just saying that we posted the same answer at almost the same time

Comment: No worries, the OP got their problem solved which is all that matters!